# Storing multiple values in one field (IDs of images liked by user)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site that allows users to vote on images. Each image has a unique id number. For voting restriction purposes, I'd like to keep track of what each user has liked. How would I go about setting up a row in the USERS table that holds all the different id numbers of the images liked by this particular user?

Comment: You need another table. This is considered a multivalue attribute. So, you would setup another table that is some how linked to the user, most likely by their userid. Then you would have an attribute for the image id they have voted on. If it's just a vote then that's all you need. When you want to see what they have voted on, simply do a query on that table for that user to list all the images they voted on.

Comment: pretty much what matt said, you need to normaize your database, include foreign keys, google those key words and you should be good to go mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have all this information in your users table. I persume that you have one table with all your images and one with all your users. Create a table called "user_image_like" for example. And store "user_id" and "image_id". When the user presses like on the image your script will add "user_id" and "image_id" to the table.

When you wan't to see all images liked by a user you can easly get this by a simple sql query.

Comment: Holy crap. I'm an idiot. I was thinking that the only other option would have been to make a table for each user tracking their likes and dislikes. I didn't even think of doing this, not sure why though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store such information in one table and in one field, I have the answer for you.

You can use either ways:

1. Store the IDs in a CSV format. When you fetch these values you can deal with them as you deal with a CSV file.
2. Store the IDs in an XML format. Then, you deal with it as any other XML file.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is a Many to Many relation. i.e. one user can like multiple Images and one image can be liked by multiple users.

According to normalization standards you should use these relation in separate table with user_id and image_id. whenever user like an image add a row to this table.

If you still want to store it in single table (users) then store ids in CSV format. be sure to store only unique image ids for each row.

Check this article 
http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html